# Выполнение цикла по ошибке

Tags: python

Функция sendRequest(query) отправляет запрос к серверу, если сервер недоступен, то необходимо выполнить запрос еще раз (И так, пока запрос не отправится). Когда сервер недоступен функция sendRequest возвращает ошибку. Если обернуть функцию в try except, то можно выполнить эту функцию еще раз.

Можно ли без goto организовать цикл, условием выполнения которого будет являться возникновение ошибки в данной функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно что-то вроде:

```
query_sent = False
while not query_sent:
    try:
        response = sendRequest(query)
        query_sent = True
    except:
        query_sent = False
```